# Fake "click" to activate an onclick method

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have an element with an **onclick** method.

I would like to activate that method (or: fake a click on this element) within another function.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you're using JQuery you can do:

```
$('#elementid').click();
```

Comment: it don't works to trigger the html select element onClick event that dropdown the options of the select, why?

Comment: $('#elementid').trigger( "click" );

Comment: The Question does not ask for a JQuery answer. Furthermore the vanilla syntax is practically identical yet undoubtedly faster.

Comment: I need a new kitchen - I'll call jQuery for that.

Comment: Relax guys, question was in 2008, inconsistent behavior across browsers was common and jquery was used a lot to fill those gaps. Browsers have come a long way since then.

Answer (score 85):

Once you have selected an element you can call click()

```
document.getElementById('link').click();
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.click

I don't remember if this works on IE, but it should. I don't have a windows machine nearby.

Answer (score 9):

```
var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
  view: window,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
});
var element = document.getElementById('element-id'); 
var cancelled = !element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
if (cancelled) {
  // A handler called preventDefault.
  alert("cancelled");
} else {
  // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
  alert("not cancelled");
}
```

[`element.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) is supported in all major browsers. The example above is based on an sample [`simulateClick()` function on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Comment: I don't see a sample simulateClick() there.  Why we have to copy things here, because pages change.

Comment: @JosephK - Under 'Example', click the link titled 'Creating and triggering events' and `simulateClick()` function is right there.

Comment: Ah, ok so here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 8):

I could be misinterpreting your question, but, yes, **this is possible.** The way that I would go about doing it is this:

```
var oElement = document.getElementById('elementId');   // get a reference to your element
oElement.onclick = clickHandler; // assign its click function a function reference

function clickHandler() {
    // this function will be called whenever the element is clicked
    // and can also be called from the context of other functions
}
```

Now, whenever this element is clicked, the code in `clickHandler` will execute. Similarly, you can execute the same code by calling the function from within the context of other functions (or even assign `clickHandler` to handle events triggered by other elements)>

Comment: Presumably you'd have problems if you wanted to use the "ev.target" within this click handler...

Answer (score 7):

If you're using jQuery, you need to use the `.trigger` function, so it would be something like:

```
element.trigger('click');
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 5):

Using `javascript` you can trigger [`click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) and [`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) like below example

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Clicked On : ",e.toElement);
},true);
document.addEventListener('focus',function(e){
  console.log("Focused On : ",e.srcElement);
},true);

document.querySelector("#button_1").click();
document.querySelector("#input_1").focus();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="test-button" id="button_1">
<input type="text" value="value 1" id="input_1">
<input type="text" value="value 2" id="input_2">
```

Comment: `srcElement` is a very old property and `toElement` is not working. I don't even remember them and I thought I was doing webdev since forever ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect example of where you should use a javascript library like Prototype or JQuery to abstract away the cross-browser differences.

Answer (score 2):

just call "onclick"!

here's an example html:

```
<div id="c" onclick="alert('hello')">Click me!</div>
<div onclick="document.getElementById('c').onclick()">Fake click the previous link!</div>
```

Comment: he didn't mention that he wants to fill an "event" object .. just that he wants to call the method. Plus I'm not sure what evernt object are you talking about!

Comment: All my reading today pointed to using .click(), using .onclick() solved my problem with safari 5.1.7 on win7 not recognizing .click().  chrome, FF, safari on iPad IOS6 all recognized .click(). It drove me nuts! Thanks hasen j   PS $('elementid').onclick() worked with the other browsers so there is no need to exception out for Safari 5.1.7.  I have no idea about IE since there are so many issues with it I can't get near this code to test it.  That's for another day.

Answer (score 2):

For IE there is [fireEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/library/ms536423(en-us,VS.85).aspx) method. Don't know if that works for other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used jQuery, but IIRC, the first method mentioned doesn't trigger the `onclick` handler.

I'd call the associated `onclick` method directly, if you're not using the event details.

Answer (score -3):

You can also try getting the element's onclick attribute and then passing into eval. This should work despite the big taboo over eval. I put a sample below

```
eval(document.getElementById('elementId').getAttribute('onclick'));
```

Comment: This works well unless the onclick script references something that isn't imported into the namespace of the script.