# Angular 2 testing $event: MouseEvent preventDefault and stopPropagation hasBeenCalled

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In a component, I have a function I need to write a test for.

```
toggleDropdown($event: MouseEvent): void {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.status.isopen = !this.status.isopen;
  }
```

How can I "stub" the `$event` or more precisely `MouseEvent` (for click case for example) and test the two methods `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` have been called properly?

And how to trigger this method including a proper `$event`?

I struggle defining a proper test case for this method. I tried to `spyOn` `$event` but it doesn't work properly as cannot find name `$event`

Comment: I cannot verify it at the moment, but you could try: spyOn(MouseEvent.prototype, 'preventDefault'); in combination with a manually created MouseEvent. I used this with custom DI tests.

Comment: Do you any cue on how to achieve creating a MouseEvent by hand which is "proper" and relevant?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529158/how-to-assert-a-spy-is-invoked-with-event-on-click-using-jasmine

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are checking that those two functions have been called, there is no need to. Simply pass `new Event('MouseEvent')` as an argument.