# I want to simulate false click when a user click on other div. it's possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fake “click” to activate an onclick method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347512/fake-click-to-activate-an-onclick-method)

I want to simulate false click when a user click on other div.  Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by false click?

Comment: **Yes, it's possible**. If you're going to ask a question, please ask the *right* question. Do you want to know *how* to do it, or just whether it's possible?

Answer (score 2):

If by "fake click" you mean to invoke the `onclick` event handler for a DOM object programmatically, then do it like this:

```
$("#myDiv").click( function() {
    $("someOtherElement").click();
} );
```

The first line assigns a new onclick event handler to `<div id="myDiv">`. When that element is clicked it will make the `<div id="someOtherElement">` behave as though it, too, was clicked by the user.