# Linking to a collapsed section on wiki and auto expandng

Tags: html, wiki, sections, collapsable

I want to have a table that links to sections that are collapsible and when the link is clicked, the section should be expanded. I cant figure out a way to automatically expand the content. Any ideas?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #4da6ff; border-radius: 5px;">[[#test|1]]</td>
</tr>
```

```
<div class="mw-collapsible">
 ==test==
</div>
```

Comment: You could trigger a click event on "open/close" element that usually controls the collapsable area (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347512/fake-click-to-activate-an-onclick-method). A better solution requires more details about the structure of your website, used frameworks and code examples though.

Comment: There is no website. Its on a wiki article. I would be surprised if that was supported..

Comment: A wiki article probably still is part of a wiki cms (like MediaWiki, DokuWiki, ...). If you only can modify the wiki article content I fear that you won't be able to sneak javascript into the page and thus have to contact the site owner to implement a functionality like that.