# How can an event on an HTML be called from a place other than the event itself

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

I have a dynamically generated Button element in my HTML that does a refresh:

```
<button id="b4545" type="button" onclick="ae(1657,1693,10,event.target);" title="Refresh the data">Refresh</button>
```

I would like to call the onclick event that it dynamically generates from a routine that has nothing to do with the actual mouse click event.

Is it possible to (for instance) get a reference to the button via the id (which is known) and then fish out the JS from the onclick event - and then call it?

OR - can I generate a fake onclick event for that Button?

Any ideas?

Comment: That may be the only way to go, but I know that JS has strange and useful capabilities.  I was just hoping that there was a way to just "click" the button from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically generated buttons you can use for example

```
$("#myButtonId").trigger("click");
```

over the element

Comment: The question is asking how to **call the function**, not how to define it without using the onclick attribute.

Comment: I was writing the question and submitted before time, sorry :S

Answer (score -1):

You can trigger the onClick event. If you are using jquery use

```
$(#btnId).trigger()
```

Comment: That looks like what I need!  Let me give it a try.

Comment: Refer similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347512/fake-click-to-activate-an-onclick-method

Comment: `trigger()` requires arguments

Comment: String literals require quotes